# Does Rails 2.0 do IPv6 well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel, ipv6

I'm using mongrel + apache 2.2 + mod_proxy_balancer.

apache2.2 is IPv6 well http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/bind.html#ipv6

Does Mongrel do IPv6 well?

Platform:RHEL ruby:1.8.6

/actionpack-2.0.5/lib/action_controller/request.rb

which is worried about the particularly .

Comment: Did you try it? Did you encounter any errors?

Comment: No.I investigate it and summarize it in a report now

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need support in Mongrel for IPv6 specifically so long as your front-end is Apache, but it stands to reason Mongrel will be fine in an IPv6 environment. It would really depend on what your internal network is configured with.

Comment: Thank you so much . but "TRUSTED_PROXIES = /^127\.0\.0\.1$|^(10|172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|30|31)|192\.168)\./i$
" is OK?

Comment: You may have to adjust based on experimentation. For example, 127.0.0.1 is ::1 in IPv6.